# Memory Leak in my C program

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list

The following code is working, but I am getting a memory leak.
The program is using linked list and dynamic memory function.
The Program excepts a .txt file as a command line argument.

**Example file:**

> Jacob Miller 832323244 21
>   Tom Darren 8931701830 19
>   Paul Mitchell 329797231 20
>   Here the output from Valgrind

```
==5742== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5742==     in use at exit: 324 bytes in 9 blocks
==5742==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 2 frees, 908 bytes allocated
==5742== 
==5742== 52 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 4
==5742==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==5742==    by 0x400A2C: student_record_allocate (new.c:106)
==5742==    by 0x4007EB: main (new.c:46)
==5742== 
==5742== 272 (16 direct, 256 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
==5742==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==5742==    by 0x400A1E: student_record_allocate (new.c:104)
==5742==    by 0x4008D1: parseFile (new.c:74)
==5742==    by 0x400803: main (new.c:47)
==5742== 
==5742== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5742==    definitely lost: 68 bytes in 2 blocks
==5742==    indirectly lost: 256 bytes in 7 blocks
==5742==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5742==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5742==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5742== 
==5742== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5742== ERROR SUMMARY: 66 errors from 21 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

> There is some problem here code snippet.

```
    void parseFile(char* filename, struct student_record_node** head)
    {
    FILE *fp;
    student_record_node *sn;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't Open file %s\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(!feof(fp)) {
        sn = student_record_allocate();

        fscanf(fp, "%20s", sn->record_->first_name_);
        fscanf(fp, "%20s", sn->record_->last_name_);
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &(sn->record_->student_id_));
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &(sn->record_->student_age_));

        appendNode(*head, sn);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    }

    void printNode(struct student_record_node* node)
    {
        printf("\nstruct student_record_node:\n");
        if (node) {
        printf("\tstudent first name: %s\n",node->record_->first_name_);
        printf("\tstudent second name: %s\n",node->record_->last_name_);
        printf("\tstudent id: %d\n", node->record_->student_id_);
        printf("\tstudent age: %d", node->record_->student_age_);

    }
    }

    struct student_record_node* student_record_allocate()
    {
    student_record_node *newNode=NULL;
    student_record *newRecord=NULL;

    newNode = (student_record_node *)malloc(sizeof(student_record_node));
    newRecord = (student_record *)malloc(sizeof(student_record));
    newNode->record_ = newRecord;
    newNode->next_ = NULL;

    return newNode;
    free(newNode->record_);
    }    

    {
        free(node->record_);
    free(node->next_);

    }
```

**I am freeing the above through this method**

```
    void freeNodeList(struct student_record_node* head)
    {
    student_record_node *tmp;
     while(tmp != NULL) {
     tmp=head;
     head=head->next_;   
     free(tmp);
    }
    head=NULL;
    }
```

> **Here is my full code**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    struct student_record
    {
    int student_id_;
    int student_age_;
    char first_name_[21];
    char last_name_[21];
    }s;

    struct student_record_node
    {    
    struct student_record* record_;
    struct student_record_node* next_;
    };
    typedef struct student_record student_record;
    typedef struct student_record_node student_record_node;

    void parseFile(char* filename, struct student_record_node** head);
    void printNode(struct student_record_node* node);
    struct student_record_node* student_record_allocate();
    void student_record_node_deallocate(struct student_record_node* node);
    void sortByAge(struct student_record_node** recordsHead);
    void sortById(struct student_record_node** recordsHead);
    void swap(struct student_record_node** node1, struct student_record_node** node2);
    void freeNodeList(struct student_record_node* head);
    void appendNode(struct student_record_node* head, struct student_record_node* newNode);
    void printNodeList(struct student_record_node* head);
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    student_record_node *head;
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: expected input file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /*  student_record *newRecord=NULL;
    recordsHead->record_ = newRecord;
    recordsHead->next_ = NULL;
    */
    head = student_record_allocate();
    parseFile(argv[1], &head);
    printf("Before sorting...");
    printNodeList(head);
    printf("Sorting by age...");
    sortByAge(&head);
    printNodeList(head);
    printf("Sorting by id...");
    sortById(&head);
    printNodeList(head); 
    freeNodeList(head);
    free(head);

    return 0;
    }

    void parseFile(char* filename, struct student_record_node** head)
    {
    FILE *fp;
    student_record_node *sn;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't Open file %s\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(!feof(fp)) {
        sn = student_record_allocate();

        fscanf(fp, "%20s", sn->record_->first_name_);
        fscanf(fp, "%20s", sn->record_->last_name_);
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &(sn->record_->student_id_));
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &(sn->record_->student_age_));

        appendNode(*head, sn);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    }

    void printNode(struct student_record_node* node)
    {
        printf("\nstruct student_record_node:\n");
        if (node) {
        printf("\tstudent first name: %s\n",node->record_->first_name_);
        printf("\tstudent second name: %s\n",node->record_->last_name_);
        printf("\tstudent id: %d\n", node->record_->student_id_);
        printf("\tstudent age: %d", node->record_->student_age_);

    }
    }

    struct student_record_node* student_record_allocate()
    {
    student_record_node *newNode=NULL;
    student_record *newRecord=NULL;

    newNode = (student_record_node *)malloc(sizeof(student_record_node));
    newRecord = (student_record *)malloc(sizeof(student_record));
    newNode->record_ = newRecord;
    newNode->next_ = NULL;

    return newNode;
    free(newNode->record_);
    }    

    {
        free(node->record_);
    free(node->next_);

    }

    void sortByAge(struct student_record_node **recordsHead)
    {
    int swapped, i;
    struct student_record_node *ptr1;
    struct student_record_node *lptr = NULL;

    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        ptr1 = *recordsHead;

        while (ptr1->next_ != lptr)
        {
            if (ptr1->record_->student_age_ > ptr1->next_->record_->student_age_)
            {
                swap(&ptr1, &ptr1->next_);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            ptr1 = ptr1->next_;
        }
        lptr = ptr1;
    }
    while (swapped);
    }

    void sortById(struct student_record_node** recordsHead)
    {
    int swapped, i;
    struct student_record_node *ptr1;
    struct student_record_node *lptr = NULL;

    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        ptr1 = *recordsHead;

        while (ptr1->next_ != lptr)
        {
            if (ptr1->record_->student_id_ > ptr1->next_->record_->student_id_)
            {
                swap(&ptr1, &ptr1->next_);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            ptr1 = ptr1->next_;
        }
        lptr = ptr1;
    }
    while (swapped);
    }

    void swap(struct student_record_node** node1, struct student_record_node** node2)
    {
    student_record_node *tmp, *n1, *n2;

    n1 = *node1;
    n2 = *node2;
    tmp->record_= n1->record_;
    n1->record_= n2->record_;
    n2->record_ = tmp->record_;

    }

    void freeNodeList(struct student_record_node* head)
    {
    student_record_node *tmp;
     while(tmp != NULL) {
     tmp=head;
     head=head->next_;   
     free(tmp);
    }
    head=NULL;
    }

    void appendNode(struct student_record_node* head, struct 
    student_record_node* newNode)
    {    
    student_record_node *prev, *next;

    if(head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }

    next = head;
    while(next != NULL) {
        prev = next;
        next = next->next_;
    }
    prev->next_ = newNode;
    }

    void printNodeList(struct student_record_node* head)
    {
    student_record_node *tmp = head;

    while(tmp != NULL) {
        tmp = tmp->next_;
        printNode(tmp);
    }

    }
```

Comment: About half of all linked-list posts on SO have the same problem - changing a local copy of 'head' and expecting that to propagate out of the function.  It will not.  Fix all your code that does this by either returning the new head as a function result or by passing in a double pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This code does not initialize `tmp`:

```
void freeNodeList(struct student_record_node* head) {
    student_record_node *tmp;
    while(tmp != NULL) {
        tmp=head;
        head=head->next_;   
        free(tmp);
    }
    head=NULL;
}
```

Consequently, you have undefined behavior when reading from an uninitialized variable.

You probably meant to use `head != NULL` as your `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

In `freeNodeList`, you only free the student record nodes, not the student records they contain, which means all of the records are still allocated at the end of your program, though they're unreachable since you destroyed the list.